# What's the proper format for WKT linestrings when importing into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, well-known-text

I'm trying to run the following test CSV through the Delimited Text plugin as WKT data:

```
oid,Line
1,LINESTRING((45.554194 -122.686101, 45.433001 -122.762632))
2,LINESTRING((45.432505 -122.598327, 45.423743 -122.592932))
3,LINESTRING((45.285959 -122.333998, 45.423743 -122.592932))
4,LINESTRING((45.548994 -122.514218, 45.519204 -122.679675))
5,LINESTRING((45.491189 -122.873493, 45.433001 -122.762632))
6,LINESTRING((45.380535 -122.743911, 45.397011 -122.79874))
7,LINESTRING((45.347019 -122.350363, 45.423743 -122.592932))
8,LINESTRING((45.582386 -122.689115, 45.536485 -122.65859))
9,LINESTRING((45.430841 -122.782667, 45.380535 -122.743911))
```

All I'm getting for my trouble is this error:

The layer file:///**$PATHTOFILE**?delimiter=%5B,%5D&delimiterType=regexp&wktField=Line is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map

I have to be missing something simple here, but I have no idea what it is, and Google hasn't been helpful. I'm using QGIS 1.8.0-Lisboa.

Comment: csetzkorn: you are correct, it should be LINESTRING(long lat, long lat)
I just confirmed it as I worked through some points in QGIS2.12.2-Lyon Using Lat and Long will create the lines to a different region than your existing shapes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two possibilities here (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text for more possibilities):

1. LineString - LINESTRING (30 10, 10 30, 40 40)
2. MultiLineString - MULTILINESTRING ((10 10, 20 20, 10 40),
   (40 40, 30 30, 40 20, 30 10))

Currently you have LINESTRING and (( which is wrong.

**UPDATE**
There is also a problem with the commas as Jason says, I managed to get the following to import (once I changed the delimiter to ;):

```
oid;Line
1;LINESTRING(45.554194 -122.686101, 45.433001 -122.762632)
2;LINESTRING(45.432505 -122.598327, 45.423743 -122.592932)
3;LINESTRING(45.285959 -122.333998, 45.423743 -122.592932)
4;LINESTRING(45.548994 -122.514218, 45.519204 -122.679675)
5;LINESTRING(45.491189 -122.873493, 45.433001 -122.762632)
6;LINESTRING(45.380535 -122.743911, 45.397011 -122.79874)
7;LINESTRING(45.347019 -122.350363, 45.423743 -122.592932)
8;LINESTRING(45.582386 -122.689115, 45.536485 -122.65859)
9;LINESTRING(45.430841 -122.782667, 45.380535 -122.743911)
```

Comment: Also, won't those commas in the `LINESTRING` trip it up and split it into multiple columns? Shouldn't the WKT be quoted?

Comment: Make sure you view the file in a text editor, not a spreadsheet program. I use Notepad++ to Replace All and I remove the " s

Comment: The (( was an artifact from some other things I tried. I think the main issue I was having is indeed the commas. Thanks!

Comment: Is the order of lats/longs not wrong here?

Comment: that is definitely lat/long :-)

Comment: Tab is a better field delimiter than ',' or ';' for a flat 2D table almost 100% of the time. (For starters, you almost never have to worry about quoting or escaping, because most text values don't themselves include tab characters.) It also makes the file a little more legible in tools like "less".

Comment: Long = X, Lat = Y.  These seem the wrong way around to me.