# Drawing points around circle in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point

I've got a square origin-destination matrix with 23 elements, I would like to draw each one of these elements as a point around a circle, to achieve a result like the following:

[image]

Can you suggest me a fast method to draw points around a circle?

I'm doing the following but doesn't works:

1) set central point

2) create a buffer with segments=99 and distance=50, uncheck "dissolve the result" option
[image]

3) convert shape to line, I get 99 lines
[image]

4) calculate the line length/23
[image]

5) convert line to points, set "insert additional points" to "No", use the result of line length/23 (1316383,260) in "distance" field
[image]

What I get is 396 points where the lines touch each other’s:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never used matrices so I could be wrong. But I would create a buffer from a central point (which you can add manually) and use the radius of a circle (I'm assuming the radius is the same for all of them otherwise you may have to create more buffer layers). When buffering, set the *segments to approximate* to 99 to have a smoother perimeter:

[image: Point and buffer]

You can then use **Convert polygons to lines** on the buffer layer.

[image: Polygon to line]

And with the output, use **Convert lines to points** (both tools are from SAGA via the Processing Toolbox). This should give you a point layer which lies on the circumference of the circle.

[image: Line to points]

Hope this helps.

---

**EDIT**:

When you use **Convert polygon to lines**, calculate the length of line via the Field Calculator by creating a new column (select Decimal numbers) and inserting this into the expression:

`$length / 23`

This will give the same length for each "segment".

Now when you run the **Convert lines to points** function, input the length you received into the *Insert Distance* field. This will produce a 23 points at the same length:

[image: 23 points]

---

**Alternative method**:

Take your final Step 5 layer (with the 396 points) and open up the Attribute Table and **Field Calculator**. Create a new integer column (eg. RowNum) and insert this expression:

```
$rownum
```

This provides each field with a unique value. Next, select the **Advanced Filter (Expression)** at the bottom of the Attribute Table:

[image: Select Advanced Filter]

And enter this command (replace "RowNum" with your named column):

```
("RowNum") %17
```

This expression skips every 17th field (396/23 = 17, we want to keep every 17th field). Select **ALL** those fields shown and **DELETE** them. Then select the **Show All Features** at the bottom of the Attribute Table. You should now (let's all pray!) have 23 points. Remember to also save!

Comment: thanks for your help @Joseph, I'm trying to have 23 points equally distanced from the center and from each other, but if in the buffer option I write 23 in the segment section I don't get 23 segments... any suggestion?

Comment: Hi Matteo, do you need these points as actual data points or are you using it for visualisation?

Comment: I'm using these to visualize connection between them in a circular layout, so I might say for visualization, but I'm not sure about what do you mean with "data points". I will need to  merge attributes on each points though.

Comment: Thanks Matteo, yes I meant if you need to perform analytical operations with them. Edited the post.

Comment: mmmmhhh I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

Comment: What is the result you are getting? Perhaps you can edit your question to include screenshots?

Comment: question edited!

Comment: Keep the buffer segments to **99** (I think it's impossible to use that option to get 23 segments: if you select the minimum of 5, you get 21 segments; 6 gives 25 segments. You can find out how it's calculated [here](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2013-November/025026.html)). Your Step 5 should give you the 23 points, not sure why it doesn't. Hopefully others can also advise.

Comment: question edited with more details, perhaps you could spot the error!

Comment: Thanks Matteo. Right...edited post to include an alternative method. Let's see if this works ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think this may create the points you need, in a simpler manner (I used a spreadsheet, because it is easier, but this could be done inside QGIS, too:

a) You want "n" points, in your case, 23.  Calculate the value of 2*pi/n.   This is the angle between each of your points [ "angle" ]

b) Create a column ["ID"] with the numbers 1 to n ; n=23 in your case

c) in the next two columns, save the results of this expression:

     sin( angle * (ID-1));   The first ID is really at 0 degrees

     cos( angle * (ID-1))

   These are the x-y coordinates of all your points

d) Create 2 more columns.  These will be the other endpoints for line segments.  Insert all the values from the first two columns, but shift down one row:  Row 2 for this pair of columns contains the values for Row 1 in the first pair of columns.

e) for row 1, of this second pair, place the value of row n (23) of the first column

You now have 5 columns:

   First column is the point ID

   Columns 2-3 and Columns 4-5 represent the line segments

So, now you have: points, line segments, or a polygon, depending on what you do with the data.

I crafted a spreadsheet to do this in about 2 minutes.  If I were using it, I would export the excel spreadsheet to CSV or somesuch, and import as needed, that is, into points, lines or a polygon.

If I figure out how to import a spreadsheet, here, or post an image at least of it, I will.

Comment: Importing CSV data as point coordinates is an easy task for QGIS with "Add delimited text" using the icon with the comma symbol. Lines can be imported if you have a column formatted as WKT: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34342/whats-the-proper-format-for-wkt-linestrings-when-importing-into-qgis