# PyQGIS - Syntax for importing WKT file

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, well-known-text

I couldn't find any proper example of how to import a .csv with WKT coordinates (Polygon) in PyQGIS.

Here are more details on my .csv. I am working with polygons. The delimiter is a semi colum, and the name of the variable that contains the relevant coordinates is WKT . Thus I wrote :

1) `uri = "data/idf.csv?delimiter=%s&crs=ESPG:2154&wktField=%s" % (";", "WKT")`

2) `idf_stats_csv = QgsVectorLayer(uri,"idf","delimitedtext")`

But this does not work. Do you have any more advice?

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34342/whats-the-proper-format-for-wkt-linestrings-when-importing-into-qgis) might help.

Comment: Hi Flo, perhaps you can [edit your question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/141992/edit) to include the information from your comment please? That way, it's more readable to those who are in a position to help you. At the moment, this is beyond me =)

Comment: Thx for your advice Joseph

Comment: Apparently, you're missing the `file:///` prefix, try something like: `uri = "file:///path/to/your/data/idf.csv?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:2154&wktField=%s" % (";", "WKT")`

Comment: I also tried it before but this does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: I thing the problem is forgod setting decimal delimiter, but a simple way to know the correct formalism is to load the layer in qgis desktop and display its source, e.g. moving the mouse on the layer legend or showing it's metadata... or showing it via python console

Answer (score 1):

```
uri ='file:///C://Users//Documents//Filepath//WKT_file.csv?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:2154&wktField=%s' % (";", "WKT")
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Name_of_new_temp_output_layer','delimitedtext')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

This should work. It worked for me.