# Converting shp file to wkt polygon string using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, well-known-text

I used the following code to convert .shp file to .wkt.

The code was successful but where can I find the .wkt file (the print row ouput)?

Is it possible to add a path for the wkt files to be stored in?

```
import arcpy
InFile = r"C:\TEST.shp"
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(InFile,["SHAPE@WKT"]):
    print row[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches.  I would use basic python [file input/output](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).  Something like below should work:

```
shp = r"C:\TEST.shp"
wkt = r"C:\TEST.wkt" # or TEST.txt
with open(wkt, "w") as f:
    for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, ["SHAPE@WKT"]):
        f.write(row[0])
        f.write("\n") # insert new line
```

However, depending on what you plan to do with the WKT strings, you will need to format it properly.  For example, see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34342/whats-the-proper-format-for-wkt-linestrings-when-importing-into-qgis).

Answer (score 0):

Well, a simple way is to store it in python within a list:

```
import arcpy
InFile = r"C:\TEST.shp"

tobefilled = []   # creates an empty list which is filled by the cursor
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(InFile,["SHAPE@WKT"]):
    print row[0]
    tobefilled.append(row[0])

print tobefilled
```

Or you create an empty file like this

```
text = open("output.txt", "w") # w stands for 'write' access

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(InFile,["SHAPE@WKT"]):
    text.write(row[0]\n)

text.close()
```

Didn't test the code, but something like this should do.

Comment: Thanks, I run the first script and it said "Succeeded" but where can I find the "print tobefilled". This what happened with the code in question, it said succeeded but I cannot find the print outcomes. I thought it might be a  ".wkt" file  stored in the .shp file folder but it did not. I think I am missing something!

Comment: I don't know where you execute your code. When you execute it in the Python window ArcMap (ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2) then it's directly printed in the python window. When I use my Editor (here: pycharm) then it's written to the Pyhon console. But Python doesn't create a new file unless you advice him to (see second example). So the first example is just written to the python interface. No wkt is created and no shape-file is changed. The print command gives you just a feedback on the screen!