# Construct a shapefile from information in a dBase file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, dbf

I am using QGIS. I have been provided a dbf file but no shp or index files. Each line in the `.dbf` file corresponds to a line I wish to show on the map. Each line in the `.dbf` file has a unique identifier and a start lat lon for the line and an end lat lon for the line. How do I construct a `.shp` and index files for this data from the `.dbf` file?

Comment: If you treat this as creating a new shapefile, as if from a CSV, instead of adding `.shp`/`.shx`, you'll probably have an easier time.

Comment: You can get some ideas from this [list](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=csv+line+%5Bqgis%5D) or this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/287731/84870)